# Finding which of the given two sets of pairs is co-prime.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request

If $p,q,r,s$ are integers s.t. $ps - qr = \pm 1$, and $a,b,a{'}, b{'}$ are 
integers such that : $a{'} = pa + qb, b{'} = ra + sb$.

From the equality: $ps - qr = \pm 1$, it can be seen that only the following sets of two pairs  <del>are</del>  can be co-prime:(i): (a) $p,q$, (b) $r,s$; 
(ii): (a) $p,r$, (b) $q,s$.

By the given second set of equalities: $a{'} = pa + qb, b{'} = ra + sb$, find 
that only co-prime pairs can be $(p,q), (r,s)$in each of the two equalities of 
the second set.
Then, their $\gcd =1$, i.e. $(p,q)=(r,s)=1$, and hence $a{'} = c, b{'} = d, 
\exists c,d \in \mathbb {Z}$.

Is my logic correct, unduly long and hence redundant somewhere?

Comment: Not following.   Each of the pairs is co-prime, clearly.  That is, $\gcd (p,r)=1$ as any common factor would be a divisor of $1$ (the others are similar).  Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: @lulu So, you mean that both sets are co-prime, i.e. (i): (a) $p,q$, (b) $r,s$; 
(ii): (a) $p,r$, (b) $q,s$. And, it is just a matter of choosing which set of two pairs we choose for the problem at hand.

Comment: What do you mean, both sets?   I am saying that each of the four pairs you wrote down are coprime.  Specifically, I mean that $\gcd(p,q)=\gcd(r,s)=\gcd(p,r)=\gcd(q,s)=1$.  I have no idea what it means for two sets to be coprime.

Comment: @lulu Thanks for clarifying, that all four are co-prime, i.e. $(p,q)=(p,r)=(s,q)=(s,r)=1$.I would also request a simple scenario in which these occur.

Comment: @lulu Thanks a ton. But, hoped for the last comment's answer.